PermissionError: [Errno 13] - Python code works on local machine but does not work in production
I code on linux machine localy with test user that has sudo privlideges. My code works there but I tried the same code in production but it gave this error code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../pooch/utils.py", line 249, in make_local_storage
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.u2net'

...

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.u2net' | Pooch could not create data cache folder '/root/.u2net'. Will not be able to download data files.


The user and user group for exection is non-root. I tried to add that user to root user group as well but it still did not work.

First, do not add users to the root group, that is how you make security holes. Second, it's clear the problem is in this .../pooch/utils.py file & you need to fix it. Since you have not detailed or printed out what path equals, we cannot help you.

What is the full path to directory on the local machine where it is trying to create the data cache directory .u2net? Only root has access /root so if it is trying to create it there at /root/.u2net in production, then it will fail with the error message that you are seeing.
